# Having blocking on logshipping msdb.dbo.log_shipping_monitor_history_detail, when I am looking where it is initiated I only see SQL Server log shippin

Tags: sql, sql-server, log-shipping

I having blocking on logshipping `msdb.dbo.log_shipping_monitor_history_detail`, when I am looking where it is initiated I only see SQL Server log shipping.

The complete query is

```
delete from msdb.dbo.log_shipping_monitor_history_detail 
where agent_id = @agent_id 
  and agent_type = @agent_type 
  and log_time_utc < @cutoff_time_utc
```

This is a target server for logshipping and most of the database are in standby/readonly mode around 30+ databases are active on this logshipping.

Please see screenshot of the running query and the one that is blocking.

Because there is a lot of blocking with this query I am seeing other jobs are waiting for worker.

We have tried changing the job timings but it seems this is not related. It seems the cleanup query is being called on a different app and not in the job

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdiak.jpg)

Comment: This `delete` query [definitely comes from `sp_cleanup_log_shipping_history`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/308632/log-shipping-is-failing-with-a-could-not-cleanup-history) - are you sure there isn't a job that's been running? Or multiple?

Comment: (And honestly, if you have access to the job steps where this procedure is called, I would probably comment it out on every single one of them, and write your own that singularly deletes history over a certain age _regardless_ of agent id, perhaps in batches. Then 30 jobs won't be competing with each other.)

Comment: I don't see any job related running with this step. Normally I see the job running this query when i use sp_whoisactive but when I ran this I see on the program sql log shipping so I can't stop this job

Comment: This thing is ran by logshipping,we use a lot of it and sometimes the table gets quite big and if you run multiple databases in same schedule the delete can block each other. I would suggest add soem index or do your own cleaning a bit earlier or change so you don't run too many jobs at the same tine